# How to easily center using Positioned and MediaQuery?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Could someone help me figure out how to use the `Positioned` widget in a `Stack` to center a **Widget** given that I have the `screenHeight` and `screenWidth`?

What I always do is use the `left/right/top/bottom` properties and use my eyes to center something, but I feel like given the `MediaQuery` there must be some way to *divide the width and height* in half or so and center. I just can't wrap my head around the simple math currently.

Comment: You can use container with full width and height that you want then for that specific element you can use align() to center that one

Comment: @Shojaeddin Thank you, that works! I also found `Positioned.fill` with `Align` works the same way. If you add it as an answer I shall mark it as the best answer, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use container with full width and height that you want then for that specific element you can use align() to center that one